# ActiveRecord RecordNotFound for other class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement an index view for questions where you can select a tag link to filter the questions to those with that tagging. I have a class method in Question where it returns only the tagged posts. Rails is giving me an error on the Tag class name in that method, although it works in the console.

None of the RecordNotFound questions on StackOverflow seem to be about referencing another class. Any advice on debugging this type of stuff or what could be going on?

I'm using Rails 5.2.0 and Ruby 2.4.2.

Error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Tag):

app/models/question.rb:13:in `tagged'
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:6:in `index'

NameError: uninitialized constant Mime::HTML
```

Questions index.html.erb

```
<h2>Questions</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class = "tags">
        <% Tag.all.each do |t| %>
            <%= link_to t.name, questions_path(tag: t.name), class: 'badge badge-primary'%>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if current_user.customer? %>
            <%= render "question" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render "admin_question" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="paginator">
    <% @questions = @questions.page(params[:page]).per(10) %>
    <%= paginate @questions, remote: true %>
</div>
```

Questions controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        if params[:tag]
            @questions = Question.tagged(:tag).page(params[:page]).per(10)
        else
            @questions = Question.page(params[:page]).per(10)
        end
    end
```

Models

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :body
    has_many :answers
    has_many :users, through: :answers
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings

    def to_s
        self.body
    end

    def self.tagged(tag)
        Tag.find_by_name!(tag).questions
    end
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :questions, through: :taggings
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error you can see that it occurred in your controller on line 6.

The problem is with `Question.tagged(:tag)`. Here you are filtering questions that are tagged with the tag `:tag` and you probably haven't created a tag with name `:tag`. I believe you wanted to filter questions that are tagged with a tag that is passed in params, so you should use `Question.tagged(params[:tag])`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'm still getting used to the params syntax. It's obvious once someone points it out.